# Model custom client side validation

Tags: validation, model, yii2

I have created a custom validator class named "EndTimeValidator" in common\components namespace.

**Code:**

```
namespace common\components;

use yii\validators\Validator;

class EndTimeValidator extends Validator
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->message = 'Event EndTime must be greater than StartTime.';
    }

    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        $startDate = $model->StartDate;
        $endDate = $model->EndDate;

        $startTime = $model->StartTime;
        $endTime = $model->EndTime;

        if( ($startDate == $endDate) &&  $startTime != "" && $endTime != ""  )
        {
            if( strtotime($endTime) < strtotime($startTime) )
            {
                $this->addError($attribute, $this->message);
            }
        }
    }

    public function clientValidateAttribute($model, $attribute, $view)
    {
        $startDate = $model->StartDate;
        $endDate = $model->EndDate;

        $startTime = $model->StartTime;
        $endTime = $model->EndTime;

        if( ($startDate == $endDate) &&  $startTime != "" && $endTime != ""  )
        {
            if( strtotime($endTime) < strtotime($startTime) )
            {
                return <<<JS
    messages.push($this->message);
JS;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in model I first included that path and defined the validation as below:

```
use common\components\EndTimeValidator;

['EndTime', EndTimeValidator::class],
```

**Question updated:**

But it is giving me below exception:

> Call to a member function getAttributeLabel() on a non-object

I have referred to this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#implementing-client-side-validation). Am I doing anything wrong? Please guide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. But I will keep this question as it may help someone.

The error was due to the following line in the **validateAttribute** function

```
$this->addError($attribute, $this->message);
```

Replace the above line with:

```
$model->addError($attribute, $this->message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
use common\components\EndTimeValidator;

/** .... */

['EndTime', EndTimeValidator::class],
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But after that it is still giving me another error. I have updated the question. Can you please help again?